# how does pointer adressing work in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, implementation, addressing

I am confused about pointer pointing to address of variable
[image]

it points to last two bytes how does this work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    short *j  = (short*)&i;
    cout << *j << endl;
}
```

.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A pointer normally holds the address of the beginning of the referred-to item.

From the sound of things, you're apparently using a little-endian system [edit: which is no surprise -- just for example, current (Intel) Macs and all Windows machines are little-endian], which means the least significant byte of your 4-byte int comes *first* in memory instead of last:

0000001 00000000 00000000 00000000

When you use a pointer to short to look at the first two bytes, you get:

0000001 00000000

which is exactly how it expects to see a value of 1 represented as a two-byte number, so that's what you get.

As implied by the name "little-endian" there are also big-endian systems, where the data would be laid-out as you've illustrated above. On such a machine, you'd probably get the results you expected. Just to be complete, there are also a few systems that use rather strange arrangements that might run something like byte1 byte0 byte3 byte2.

Comment: thanks jerry coffin do all desktops/lapts have little endian systems?

Comment: Your first two sentences make it sound like you're saying little-endian systems are abnormal, or that their pointers don't point at the beginning of the referred-to item. It's really a matter of which end is considered the beginning.

Comment: @SRN: mostly, yes. Anything running Windows is little-endian, and current (Intel) Macs are as well. Some of the ARM-powered machines *may* be big-endian (ARM can run in either little-endian or big-endian mode).

Comment: @Robᵩ: I was wondering if anybody would recognize that... :-)

Comment: @RobKennedy: I'm not sure how it could be read that way, but I've edited to clarify.

Comment: It was the *though*, which you've now removed. It works like *however*, and made it sound like the second sentence was an exception to what the first sentence claimed.

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with byte order. Your architecture stores an `int` 1 as:

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
^^^^^^^^
  this is the address that is stored in the pointer.
|------- -------- -------- --------| int (4 bytes)
|------- -------|                    short (2 bytes)
```

which, truncated to a `short` of 2 bytes still is a 1.

Btw. try printing all bytes on their own:

```
unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&i;
for (unsigned j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++) {
  std::cout << p[j] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

It should print `1 0 0 0`, and *not* `0 0 0 1` as suggested in your question.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the architecture. And the specific implementation should be completely irrelevant (if it isn't you are doing something wrong).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the endianness of your system (x86 is typically little-endian).

In big endian, the value of i will be stored with the most significant byte first :

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

In little endian, the value of i will be stored with the least significant byte first :

```
00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

In any case, the pointer will point to the beginning of the number. However, since your system is little-endian, casting that pointer to short and dereferencing to get a short value, you will get the first two bytes of the little endian value

```
00000001 00000000
```

In little endian, this is the short value for 1, which is the result you get. If you ran the exact same code on a big-endian system, you would then get a value of 0.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't point to bytes; it points to an entity of type `int`.  How an
int is represented in memory depends on the implementation.  And if `i`
is an `int`, then `*((short*)&i)` is undefined behavior; you could get
anything.  In practice, on common platforms, you can access things like
this; what you get still depends on the platform, and such manipulations
are only useful for very low level, platform specific operations.  (On an Intel, you'll get the results the others have posted.  For other platforms and other values, it depends.)